# bootstrap center horizontal inputs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So I know this has been asked before but I just can't figure out why I cannot get the input fields of a form to center themselves inside a row. I want them stacked on a mobile view.
I've made a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/7kobcax6/6/). Any help would be really appreciated.

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
 <form>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 offset-5" >
    <label for="start"></label>
    <input type="text" id="start" class="date-input-css" name="start" placeholder="From">
      </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 offset-5" >
    <label for="end"></label>
    <input type="text" id="end" name="end" class="date-input-css" placeholder="To">
        </div>
    </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the class `offset-5` on both of your inputs, you're looking for the classes `col-md-offset-2` and `col-sm-offset-2`, specifically on the first of the two inputs. Note that for Bootstrap 3, you need to specify both `col-` and the breakpoint in the class names, so a simple `offset-2` won't work.

It's an offset of `2` you're looking for, as Bootstrap columns should always add up to `12`. Because your inputs are both `4` wide, you already have `8`, leaving `4`. This means `2` either side, so you only need to offset the left-most input by `2`, as the right-most one will be offset automatically.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
div.center_me {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 center_me">
        <label for="start"></label>
        <input type="text" id="start" class="date-input-css" name="start" placeholder="From">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 center_me">
        <label for="end"></label>
        <input type="text" id="end" name="end" class="date-input-css" placeholder="To">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfect and thank you for explaining it so well.